# Which dll client version should I use to connect to both Sharepoint 2010 and Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: client-object-model, client

I have a web project that should consume both On-premise Sharepoint 2010 and Sharepoint 2013.

So, we have two different versions of the following dlls :

- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client  V 14.0.0.0
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime V 14.0.0.0
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client V 16.0.0.0
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime V 16.0.0.0

Which version of dll should I safely use to consume the API from two different server versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Just used below

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll V 16.1.5026.1200
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll 16.1.5026.1200
```

and its working fine for SharePoint 2010,2013 and Online.

Up To my knowledge latest dll will be compatible with all.

Comment: Any official reference about this?

Comment: I am not sure about this as I was unable to find any official documentation which says that the latest DLL are always compatible with lower versions of SharePoint, but when I practically tried the solution I was also able to update the list item in SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 with the use of V16 DLL.

Comment: Architecture of Client Object Model for SharePoint 2010 and above are almost same. so whenever Microsoft upgrades sharepoint, it will keep backward compatibility unless and until architecture changes.

Comment: True, and untrue. There will be a lot of errors with this approach when you are using methods in the .dll that are not supported for 2013, 2010

Comment: @RobertLindgren : Would a substitution to a newer DLL without changing the used functions be OK then? We need to update because the underlying Server is updated and does not provide .Net 2.0.